# Selecting rows from Parent Table only if multiple rows in Child Table match

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im building a code that learns tic tac toe, by saving info in a database.
I have two tables, `Games(ID,Winner)` and `Turns(ID,Turn,GameID,Place,Shape)`.
I want to find parent by multiple child infos.
For Example:

```
SELECT GameID FROM Turns WHERE
GameID IN (WHEN Turn = 1 THEN Place = 1) AND GameID IN (WHEN Turn = 2 THEN Place = 4);
```

Is something like this possible?
Im using ms-access.

> Turm - Game turn
>  GameID - Game ID
>  Place - Place on matrix
>   1=top right, 9=bottom left
>  Shape - X or circle

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you logic.. please explain what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to choose a game that has a child with info (turn = 1, place =1)
and also has a child with info (turn = 2, place = 5).
I bypassed this problem by adding another column to the table but i still want to know if there is a solution if i need it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This very simple query will do the trick in a single scan, and doesn't require you to violate **First Normal Form** by storing multiple values in a string (shudder).

```
SELECT T.GameID
FROM Turns AS T
WHERE
   (T.Turn = 1 AND T.Place = 1)
   OR (T.Turn = 2 AND T.Place = 4)
GROUP BY T.GameID
HAVING Count(*) = 2;
```

There is no need to join to determine this information, as is suggested by other answers.

**Please use proper database design principles in your database, and don't violate First Normal Form by storing multiple values together in a single string!**

Comment: I fully agree. I assumed there was such an appropriate constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to your problem can be accomplished by using a sub-query that contains a self-join between two instances of the Turns table:

```
SELECT * FROM Games
WHERE GameID IN 
(
    SELECT Turns1.GameID
    FROM Turns AS Turns1 
    INNER JOIN Turns AS Turns2 
    ON Turns1.GameID = Turns2.GameID
    WHERE (
        (Turns1.Turn=1 AND Turns1.Place = 1) 
        AND 
        (Turns2.Turn=2 AND Turns2.Place = 4))
);
```

The Self Join between Turns (aliased Turns1 and Turns2) is key, because if you just try to apply both sets of conditions at once like this:

```
WHERE (
        (Turns.Turn=1 AND Turns.Place = 1) 
        AND 
        (Turns.Turn=2 AND Turns.Place = 4))
```

you will never get any rows back. This is because in your table there is no way for an individual row to satisfy both conditions at the same time.

My experience using Access is that to do a complex query like this you have to use the SQL View and type the query in on your own, rather than use the Query Designer. It may be possible to do in the Designer, but it's always been far easier for me to write the code myself.

Answer (score -2):

```
select GameID from Games g where exists (select * from turns t where 
t.gameid = g.gameId and ((turn =1 and place = 1) or (turn =2 and place =5)))
```

This will select all the games that have atleast one turn with the coresponding criteria.

More info on exist:
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php

Comment: Hey,thanks for the answer but  I need both criteria to apply not just one.

Comment: This won't work without a self-join in the subquery, even changing the 'or' to an 'and' because no rows satisfy both conditions.

Comment: @Gary.Ray Your claim that `EXISTS` is better than `IN` is based on 10-year-old misconceptions. It is patently false that "most if not all RDBMSes... re-execute... for each row".

Answer (score -2):

I bypassed this problem by adding a column which holds the turns as a string example : "154728" and i search for it instead. I think this solution is also less demanding on the database

Comment: I don't think this is a good long-term solution, as it violates **First** Normal Form.